# How to replace yaml file properties with default value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the following kts Gradle configuration of the web application:

```
tasks.withType<ProcessResources> {
        filesMatching("application-test.yaml") {
            expand(project.properties)
        }
    }
```

The `application-test.yaml` looks like

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 25
    username: ${DB_USERNAME:user}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD:password}
    url: ${DB_CONNECT_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database}
```

When I execute the command:

```sh
./gradlew clean test -PDB_PASSWORD=password -PDB_USERNAME=error_user -PDB_CONNECT_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database
```

There is the error in the groovy script:

```
Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
SimpleTemplateScript6.groovy: 9: unexpected token:  @ line 9, column 40.
```

But if I remove default values, all is ok.
I tried to

- replace delimiter with @@/'@@'
- use \${} instead of ${}
- use the groovy code in yaml: `${DB_PASSWORD?!password}`

One thing that helped me is kts code to get and replace properties in `build.gradle.kts` with `filter<ReplaceTokens>`.

Maybe somebody knows another way?

Comment: I think you have a special character in URL. throw it in quotes and it should work:
"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database"

Comment: This way does not work too, I tested already